# How to integrate Microsoft intune SDK in a flutter application?

Tags: flutter, intune

We are trying to integrate [Microsoft Intune SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/developer/app-sdk-android)  in the flutter application.

The first blocker which looks interesting is Intune requires every activity to extend from MAMActivity. And on the other hand,  Flutter requires that android Activity should extend from FlutterActivity.

So how to overcome this issue?

Comment: Is there a package available in Flutter for intune SDK integration?

Comment: I am not aware of that. But trying through native implementation

Comment: Ok, via Platform Channel?

Comment: yes, through platform channels

Comment: There is a feature request on the Microsoft Feedback Portal for this issue. Might be something you like to upvote: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/d396bfa8-e28c-ed11-a81b-000d3ae32cd0

Answer (score 0):

In my project I integrated Intune SDK and MSAL SDK in Flutter. You have to develop a flutter plugin to implement those native SDKs using platform channels... It's not easy, but is the way.